# How to make a windows forms application update by itself?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've Developed a Windows Forms App having about 5 forms intended for students of a particular college. I need to know how to update my app (Updating the attendance percent of the student and so on)by downloading files from the internet or through any other method. I'm looking for a way in which the user does not feel that its too complicated to run the app. I'm not familiar with SQL or databases, but yet I'll try to catch up with any answers of those type.

Comment: It's been a while since I've built any WinForms apps, but [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) used to be a good solution to this problem.

Comment: The current answer and comment address the term *update* in regards to the application version, but if you read the question it is asking about how to provide data updates to the user.

Comment: Thanks.. but I tried installing my app on another user's computer which runs windows 8.1 and it gives a warning first at the time of installation and then shows that the app is unrecognized and cannot be opened.. And I used ClickOnce for deployment.. And yes.. I'm looking for data updates.. Thank you @Anthony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) by Microsoft or other third party installation applications.

Comment: Thank you.. But ClickOnce has issues regarding certificate verification on other computers.  :)